# How to enforce to input value from another column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, formula, list-validation

I've created 3 columns:

1. Choice:

   - Banana
   - Apple
   - Orange

2.Start date

3.End date

If you select "banana", then he/she must input value for "start date" and "end date".

I tried to input the formula below at start date but it doesn't work.

```
=if([Choice]="Banana",[Start date]=today(),true, false)
```

Could anyone out there help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below formula:

```
=IF([Choice]="Banana",IF(OR(ISBLANK([Start date]),ISBLANK(End date)),false,true),true)
```

This satisfy the condition: If `[Choice]` is equal to "Banana" then user cannot leave `Start date` or `End date` columns blank.

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: You need to add this formula in **Validation Settings** under **List Settings** and not column settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could use formula as Ganesh said via List settings->Validation settings->type the formula as below:

```
=IF([Choice]="Banana",IF(OR(ISBLANK([Start date]),ISBLANK(End date)),false,true),true)
```

Since the single column validate cannot refer to other column value, we cannot add the formula under certain column.